# How to select MySQL date range using PHP form data

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP form which submits data in the following format:

```
Array ( 
    [zone] => Array ( 
        [0] => East 
    ) 
    [publication] => Array ( 
        [0] => ABP 
    ) 
    [datefilter] => 09/01/2016 - 10/15/2016
)
```

I use the data to construct a MySQL query as follows:

```
  $zone_search = $_POST['zone'];
  $zone = join("','",$zone_search);
  $publication_search = $_POST['publication'];
  $publication = join("','",$publication_search);  

  $tmp = "SELECT * FROM advertisement
          WHERE zone IN('$zone')
            AND publication IN('$publication')";
```

However, I want to limit the data to the two dates given in the `$_POST['datefilter']` field. How do I add the date filter dates into my query?

The relevant columns in the database table are:

```
zone
publication
release_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following logic after the post data. Assumption date data submission follow this pattern small date - large date as per the sample posted data.

```
<?
    //$_POST['datefilter'] = '09/01/2016 - 10/15/2016';
    $zone_search = $_POST['zone'];
    $zone = join("','",$zone_search);
    $publication_search = $_POST['publication'];
    $publication = join("','",$publication_search);
```

`$dates = explode("-", $_POST['datefilter']);

echo $dt1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(trim($dates[0])));
echo "<br/>";
echo $dt2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(trim($dates[1])));

$tmp = "SELECT * FROM advertisement
      WHERE zone IN('$zone')
        AND publication IN('$publication') and release_date between $dt1 and $d2";`

Answer (score -2):

You might try to convert the dates into a timestamp using php-function `strtotime()`.  You would also need to change the column in your DB to "timestamp". Then you can just compare two integers with greater and smaller then.
e.g. `SELECT * FROM advertisement WHERE zone IN ('$zone') AND publication IN ('$publication') AND release_date > ('$timestamp_from') AND release_date < ('$timestamp_to')`